# Meta title content based on node fields

Tags: meta-tags

Is there a module that will allow me to set the default meta title for a content type to be the title field of the node displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that module would be [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)

Comment: Is it possible to set a default title tag in a view that picks up a field?

Comment: If it is a token you can use it.